# Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS - Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 2GB - How turn monitor on/off from script?

Tags: raspberrypi, monitor

I want to use cron or the like to turn on/off the attached monitor for a Rpi running MagicMirror2.

```
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ uname -a
Linux user-desktop 5.15.0-1045-raspi #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 16 13:24:44 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried xrandr:

```
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/520x1080/290+0+0  XWAYLAND0
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --off
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$
```

xset:

```
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ xset -q
<snip>
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Server does not have the DPMS Extension
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ sleep 1 && xset dpms force off
server does not have extension for dpms option
xset:  unknown option force
<snip>
```

tvservice:

```
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ sudo tvservice -o
[sudo] password for user:
tvservice is not supported when using the vc4-kms-v3d driver.
Similar features are available with standard linux tools
such as modetest from libdrm-tests.
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ sudo modetest
sudo: modetest: command not found
```

vcgencmd

```
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ vcgencmd display_power 0
VCHI initialization failed
user@user-desktop:~/MagicMirror/config$ sudo vcgencmd display_power 0
display_power=1
```

Something else I should be using or some config/software I need to install to get one of the above working?

EDIT. Tried suggestion below:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ WAYLAND_DISPLAY="wayland-1" wlr-randr --output HDMI-A-1 --off
failed to connect to display
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# From https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=360281
WAYLAND_DISPLAY="wayland-1" wlr-randr --output HDMI-A-1 --off
```

After you test it to be working, put save it to a file, mark it as executable, and register it with "cron or the like". The `WAYLAND_DISPLAY="wayland-1"` part allows processes started outside the graphical session like cron or SSH to find Wayland. `HDMI-A-1` is your main output, which you can replace to specify the other outputs on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Had to `sudo apt install wlr-randr`, then tried the above but got response "failed to connect to display" (I've added the exact details to the question above because I can't format this comment for the life of me). Note that this is a Rpi with Ubuntu Desktop installed, not PI OS.

Comment: @grover Have you tried other values of WAYLAND_DISPLAY like wayland-0 or wayland-2?